# method generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I have to create a getTotal function to find total of all number in a 2d array.
It should be applicable to float,int,long and double.
So I tried to create a generic method in Java. I have knowledge of templates in C++.
So I tried a similar approach but java compiler is showing errors.

```
public static < E > E getTotal( E arr[][],int row, int col )
{
    E total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        total=total + arr[i][j];
    }
}
return total;
}
```

I am getting these errors :

```
2darray.java:4: error: incompatible types
    E total=0;    
            ^

  required: E
  found:    int
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method getTotal(E[][],int,int)
2darray.java:7: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
        total=total + arr[i][j];
                    ^
  first type:  E
  second type: E
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method getTotal(E[][],int,int)
2darray.java:42: error: method getTotal in class darraysoperation cannot be applied to given types;
    System.out.println("Total is "+foo.getTotal(multi,5,10));
                                      ^
  required: E[][],int,int
  found: int[][],int,int
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: int
    bound(s): Object
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method getTotal(E[][],int,int)
3 errors
```

I am not getting these errors as I am beginner to generics in Java.

Comment: Primitive types and generics don't go well together. Arrays and generics don't go well together either. So arrays of primitive types and generics are pretty much incompatible. You'll have to provide one method for each type of array, just as `java.util.Arrays` does for various methods.

Comment: I am afraid JBNizet is right. If you need that functionality, just overload the method for the types you need (Integer, Long, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E is generic type. it means that you can call method getTotal with array of any type. 
for example you can call getTotal with array of String and 0 is not String.